# Organizing Shared Gmail Account

Tags: gmail

I've recently been given command of a shared Gmail account and I'm trying to find a way to organize it well.

It's shared among 7 people, all of whom have different responsibilities and need to field different emails and respond to different threads at different times.

My initial thought was to make "folders" or have each person be able to tag an email with a certain color to signal to others that it is their responsibility and that they will take care of it.

I can't quite figure out how to do that unfortunately. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the domain of your account gmail.com or a custom domain? Are you accessing the account always from one location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Individual Gmail accounts are not intended to be used by several users.

From [Share an account among users - Google Apps Help](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33330)  (this apply to Gmail consumer accounts too).

> Each Gmail account is intended and designed for use by an individual user. If you have multiple users frequently accessing the
>   same account from various locations, you may reach a Gmail threshold
>   and your account will be temporarily locked down

One alternative is use the mail delegation feature in Gmail. To learn about it, see [Set up mail delegation - Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/138350?hl=en)

Another alternative is to use a group of Google Groups as a shared Inbox. For details, see [Use a group as a collaborative inbox - Google Apps Help](https://support.google.com/a/answer/167430). Besides the article mentions Google Groups for Business, the free version could be used for that too.

Regarding the way to organize email messages in Gmail, you could use labels. Labels can be nested as if they were folders. Also you could assign colors to labels.

To learn about Labels in Gmail, see [Using labels - Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/118708?hl=en)